# Difference between direct sum of n-chains and n-chains of sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Hatcher book *Algebraic Topology* and trying to understand the proof of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. The proof itself is clear but I can't understand the differece between $C_n(A) \oplus C_n(B)$ and $C_n(A+B)$. Here $A,B$ are subspaces of a space $X$ such that $\mathring{A} \cup \mathring{B} = X$. I have a clear description in my mind of the space $C_n(A) \oplus C_n(B)$ (the set of all the pair $(a,b)$ where $a \in C_n(A)$ and $b \in C_n(B)$) and Hatcher says that $C_n(A+B)$ is the subset of $C_n(X)$ of all the n-chains that are sums of chains in $A$ and in $B$. What is the difference between these two groups? When are they not equal?

Comment: Hint: In a direct sum $V\oplus W$ the intersection of $V$ and $W$ is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious map $\alpha\colon C_n(A) \oplus C_n(B) \to C_n(A + B)$ given by $\alpha(c_A, c_B) = \iota_A(c_A) + \iota_B(c_B)$, where $\iota_Y\colon C_n(Y) \to C_n(X)$ is the homomorphism induced by inclusion of a subspace. This homomorphism is always surjective, and if $A\cap B = \emptyset$ then $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

However, suppose $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ and let $\sigma\colon \Delta^n \to A\cap B$ be a singular $n$-simplex. By composing with the inclusion maps $A\cap B\to A$ and $A\cap B \to B$ we get singular $n$-simplices $\sigma_A \in C_n(A)$ and $\sigma_B \in C_n(B)$ such that $\alpha(\sigma_A, 0) = \alpha(0, \sigma_B) = \iota_{A\cap B}\sigma$; in other words, $\alpha$ is not injective unless $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

For an extreme example, if $A = B$ then $C_n(A + B) = C_n(A)$ and $C_n(A) \oplus C_n(B) = C_n(A)^2$.

This is analogous to the difference between the vector spaces $V \oplus W$ and $V + W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of a common vector space so that internal $+$ makes sense). In both cases every element can be written as sum of something in $V$ with something in $W$, but in $V\oplus W$ this sum is *unique* and in $V + W$ it is not unless $V\cap W = \{0\}$.